# Using API with Node & Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, api

Trying to build a language translating messaging app using Node & Angular. Using an API called Yandex(Google translate isnt free). www.yandex.com

I am not sure if I even have the right approach, its my first time implementing APIs into my project.

SO I have a simple FORM

```
<div ng-controller="messageController">
    <h4>Send Message</h4>
    <form>
        <textarea name="message" ng-model='message.msg'></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" ng-click='sendMessage()' class="btn btn-info">
    </form>
</div>
```

Which goes to the messageController

```
myapp.controller('messageController', function($scope, messageFactory, $location, $rootScope) {
        $scope.sendMessage = function(){
            console.log("Inside sendMessage()" + $scope.message.msg)
            messageFactory.translateMessage($scope.message.msg, function (data){
                console.log(data);
            })
        }
})
```

and this is the Factory making the API call with my api key.

```
myapp.factory('messageFactory', function($http, $location) {
        var factory = {};
        factory.translateMessage = function(info, callback) {
            console.log("Inside Message Factory-Traslate", info)

            $http.get('https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=<ENTER_KEY_HERE>&text='<info>'&lang=<ga>&[format=<plain>]').success(function (output){
                callback(output);
            })
        }
        return factory;
    });
```

PS: I have obviously replaced the key here.

This is the link im following https://tech.yandex.com/translate/doc/dg/reference/translate-docpage/#JSON.

Though have a feeling this is not how I am supposed to make an API call.

How do i make the API request and get back the response?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: may i know what is the specific issue here ?

Comment: did you test your solution? Have you got errors or something wrong?

Comment: Yes I did, it doesn't return with any data at all.

Comment: You should return a promise (`$http.get` already returns one) instead of taking a callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to provide more info about what errors you are getting, but in your code, where you are making the API call, the URL should look something like -

```
var url = 'https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=' + key + '&text=' + info + '&lang=ga&format=plain'
```

So your code would look like this -

```
var key = 'yourActualKey'
var url = 'https://translate.yandex.net/api/v1.5/tr.json/translate?key=' + key + '&text=' + info + '&lang=ga&format=plain'

$http.get(url).success(function (output) {
    callback(output)
})
```

You don't have to include the <> or [] as part of your params. Those are just used to denote placeholders<>, and optional params[].

Also I'd recommend using `.then` rather than `.success` to handle your Promise.

[Official docs on $http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

Comment: Thank you so much, used ur suggestions and it worked. But have kept my Promise as .success. havent changed it to .then. What is the difference ? 

okay i see the official docs, il check it out.

Comment: angular is deprecating its .success promise method, so in the future, these might not work at all .. also you can read [this](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/angular-promises%E2%80%93then-vs-success)